# Rearrange UITableView with a struct variable?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, struct

I'm trying to re order a table with variables from a struct.
I know it works with strings, something like below.

```
var items:[String] = ["Item one", "item two", "item three"]
```

Re order method

```
   override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt fromIndexPath: IndexPath, to: IndexPath) {
    let item:String = items[fromIndexPath.row]
    self.items.remove(at: fromIndexPath.row)
    items.insert(item, at: to.row)
    self.tableView.reloadData()
```

I've managed to get my "summery" variable to appear on the cell and the "text" variable in my viewController. However I'm having trouble figuring out how to re order using a struct variable. I believe it's something like this?

Wha't ive tried so far (below) gives me an error: can't convert type String to Item

The struct in a class (Items.swift)

```
struct Item {

var summery: String
var text: String

}

var items:[Item]
```

Re order method

```
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt fromIndexPath: IndexPath, to: IndexPath) {
 var item = Items.sharedInstance
 let itemToMove:String = item.items[fromIndexPath.row].summery
 item.items.remove(at: fromIndexPath.row)
// Problem is on line below //
 item.items.insert(itemToMove, at: to.row)
 self.tableView.reloadData()
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's cause you are trying to insert **String** to array of **Item** structs

Replace

```
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt fromIndexPath: IndexPath, to: IndexPath) {
   var item = Items.sharedInstance
   let itemToMove:String = item.items[fromIndexPath.row].summery
   item.items.remove(at: fromIndexPath.row)
  // Problem is on line below //
   item.items.insert(itemToMove, at: to.row)
   self.tableView.reloadData()
 }
```

with

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt fromIndexPath: IndexPath, to: IndexPath) {
     var item = Items.sharedInstance
     let itemToMove = item.items[fromIndexPath.row]
     item.items.remove(at: fromIndexPath.row)
     item.items.insert(itemToMove, at: to.row)
     self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```